# Is it possible to stop MSSQL Connection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am currently developing an application that will connect to a SQL server. Is it possible to stop or abort the connection after failing for the first time of attempting to Open the connection or 15 seconds after the Connection.Open() sent?

Sample code below:

```
     Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
     conn.ConnectionString = connstr
         Try
            conn.Open()
'Drop or abort the connection after 15 seconds or after failing the first attempt to connect
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: You can handle the requested code in the Catch block. Additionally there is a finally block that executed after success or failed states.

Comment: The `ConnectionTimeout` property is 30 (seconds) by default. You can change it to 15 if you want. A specific `SqlException` will be thrown if that time period expires without a successful connection.

Comment: Actually, I have to correct myself there. It's actually the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` property that defaults to 30. The `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` property is already 15 by default. It seems like you already have what you want, although *"failing for the first time of attempting to Open the connection or 15 seconds after the Connection.Open() sent"* are two very different things.

Comment: Hi, actually I already tried to set the ConnectionTimeout property in my connection string but error shows after around 30 seconds to 45 seconds, sometimes at exact 15 seconds.